# Equation in Pseudocode problem

Tags: equations, algorithmic, pseudocode

I am trying to write a pseudocode in Latex including an equation. My MWE is the following

```
'\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Fuzzy c-means clustering algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State Choose primary centroids $v_{k}$
    \State Compute the membership degree of all feature vectors in all clusters
    \begin{equation}
     u_{ki}  = \frac{1}{ \sum_{j=1}^C ( \frac{D^{2}(x_{i} - v_{k})}{D^{2}(x_{i} - v_{j})})^\frac{2} 
    {m-1}}   
    \label{updateU}\\
  \end{equation}

  \end{algorithmic}

  \end{algorithm}
```

And I get the results shown in the picture: [image: results]

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using packages `algorithm` and `algorithmicx`, the following works (just removed `\\`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Fuzzy c-means clustering algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State Choose primary centroids $v_{k}$
        \State Compute the membership degree of all feature vectors in all clusters
        \begin{equation}
            u_{ki}  = \frac{1}{ \sum_{j=1}^C ( \frac{D^{2}(x_{i} - v_{k})}{D^{2}(x_{i} - v_{j})})^\frac{2} 
            {m-1}}   
            \label{updateU} % removed \\
        \end{equation}
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

(By the way, it's best if the MWE you provide is compilable, i.e. that one can copy-paste it into an editor and directly compile it; rarely (never?) should you shy away from including what `documentclass`, packages, etc. you need for your MWE.) All the best!

Comment: Thank you for your answer